# Make quality gate pass manually

Tags: sonarqube, quality-gate

I'm using SQ 6.2 with quality profile "Sonar Way" and quality gate also "SonarWay".

After some refactorings the QG fails with new issues and coverage on new code (which is not really new). I'd like the project to pass the QG (because no new code was added), so I marked the new issues as "Won't fix", but I found no way to accept the coverage failure.

Is there a way to manually mark the QG green or set the leak period?

Answer (score 4):

There is no manual override for the Quality Gate. You'll have to either change the quality gate conditions (or temporarily? apply a less strict QG to the project) or fix the problem.

Comment: Well, I could surely do this, but imho this behaviour does not meet the main concern "fixing the leak". As there is no leak this behaviour is just an impediment in my development workflow. 
btw, what's the criteria for SQ to detect code as "new code"?

Comment: You're right @Frank, but you're the one that wanted to override the quality gate without actually changing any code. :-)